# Find the Norm(Inner product)

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, inner-products

**Find $\|xe^{-x}\|$(Find the Norm with respect to the inner product below).**

The inner product is defined as $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(x)dx$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use the relation that links the inner product with the norm, this boils down to calculating $\int_{-1}^1 x^2\exp(-2x)\mathrm{d}x.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Know that, **Norm: <p , p> =** $\sqrt{(p)^2}$ , where **p** = $xe^{-x}$

**Step 1**: First, Calculate the $\int^{1}_{-1} (xe^{-x})^2 dx$.

= $ \frac{e^2}4 - \frac{5e^{-2}}4$.

**Step 2:** Next, get the **square root** of $\frac{e^2}4 - \frac{5e^{-2}}4$.

**Answer**: $\frac{\sqrt{e^4 - 5}}{2e}$.